# What is the most versatile array to string serialization method?

Tags: arrays, serialization

I'm particularly interested in the following features:

- possibility of modifying the
  serialized array using regular
  expressions or other simple methods,
- being able to parse the string using
  standard tools in various programming
  languages,
- serialization of simple arrays as well as associative arrays (objects),
- conciseness and human
  readability,

I've been looking into JSON, url-encoding, Rison, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is quite versatile, allowing for basic objects, arrays and primitives (no classes though) as well as nested objects/arrays, and it's very well supported in many programming languages.

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking what the most **versatile** method is, I would suggest `XML` despite its clunky nature.  It is verbose, but allows for more flexibility than `JSON` which is primarily valuable in its light syntax and ease of parsing.

I still prefer `JSON` in most situations.